# About the heat capacity and enthalpy

Tags: thermodynamics

Does the expression $$ C_{p} = \left ( \frac{\partial H}{\partial T} \right )_{p} $$ still work when the work done by other things than expansion (by chemical reactions, electric work etc) is not zero?

Comment: What makes you think it only applies to zero work?

Comment: You wrote the P is being held constant.  What else is being held constant, say,, when you are considering chemical reactions?  Also, are the quantities in your equation per mole?  If so, per mole of what?